# Count messages of all users using a Slack App

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to build a slack app that will count how many messages a user sent to each other user in the workspace.
I read the documentation multiple times, but am still not sure about the following:
 1. To my understanding I could only see this information for the users who installed my app, right? So if employee 1 installed my app in the workspace and employee 2 gave the app the relevant permissions(?), I would see all conversations in which employees 1 or 2 participated. but if for example employee 3 is talking in a private chat/channel with employee 4 - I will not be aware of this? 
 2. What will be the best way to retrieve that information? either once in X days use the API to get all the messages of the employees who approved my app or use the webhooks and be notified of every message sent in realtime? 
 3. In order to count how many messages sent, I only need "metadata scope", but after reading the documentation it seems no such scope exists. Is there another way of getting only the metadata about the message (just who sent it and to whom)

Thanks!